# How to make Proguard keep the class method names and attribute names as it is?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

As above.

My ProGuard config is

```
-keepclassmembers public class myApp.interfaces.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames public class myApp.interfaces.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepparameternames
```

Really new to this and no real idea what I'm doing.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make Proguard not change the method and variable names of all Classes inside `myApp.interfaces.*`. If they want to rearrange some algo stuff to optimise it or whatever, it's fine. As long as the names are not changed.

This must be done because of the Serializable issue between server and client.

Comment: -keep class myApp.interfaces.*{ *;}

Comment: Thanks, you're a real lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:
`-keep class myApp.interfaces.** { *; }`

It will not touch the class or its members. If you get errors / warnings, Rebuild the project.